# How to parse php variable into xml tag..?

Tags: php, xml, tags

```
<Address FormattedInd="true">
      <CityName>Athens Center</CityName>
           <County>'.$Country.'</County>
      <CountryName Code="GR" />  
</Address>
```

For County I can use as `<County>'.$Country.'</County>`. where `$Country="CountryName"`
But for single tag like CountryName Code="GR"  How can I pass the code "GR" as a PHP Variable.
Here, `<CountryName Code="GR" />` I need the "GR" to be passed from a variable say `$Code = "GR";`

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a function;

```
function GenerateXML($tagname, $value)
{
    return "
        <{$tagname}>
            {$value}
        </{$tagname}>
    ";    
}
```

Or alternatively, in a PHP file

```
<?
print "<tagname>{$value}</tagname>";
?>
```

Either way is valid

Self closing tags;

```
function XMLSelfClose($tagname, $valuename, $value)
{
    return "<{$tagname} {$valuename}='{$value}' />";
}

print "<{$tagname} {$valuename}='{$value}' />";
```

Comment: How possible in self closing xml tag? Here, <CountryName Code="GR" />   I need the "GR" to be passed from a variable.

Comment: Edited the Question..Please review

Comment: Where to call function XMLSelfClose($tagname, $valuename, $value) this function..?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using SimpleXML than using strings to create your XML, you can easily mess up the content if you start to build the data as you are.

Your above content can be created using...

```
$Country = "Greece";
$Code = "GR";

// Create base document
$xml =new SimpleXMLElement('<Address FormattedInd="true"></Address>');
// Add in the CityName elment
$xml->addChild("CityName", "Athens Center");
$xml->addChild("Country", $Country);
$countryName = $xml->addChild("CountryName");
// With the CountryName element just created, add the Code attribute
$countryName->addAttribute("Code", $Code);

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Which outputs...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Address FormattedInd="true"><CityName>Athens Center</CityName><Country>Greece</Country><CountryName Code="GR"/></Address>
```